# CalculateField_management - updating fields with X and Y coordinates for start and end of line

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I've searched all the help documents and can't see where my script is going wrong.

[image]

I've tried adding the fields as FLOAT, replacing "PYTHON_9_3" with just "PYTHON" but it just doesn't work. The field get created fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Add Geometry Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000191000000) tool (no code needed). This tool is new in 10.2.1.

Comment: I've tried arcpy.CalculateField_management(RtNET,"SX","!SHAPE!.firstpoint.X", "PYTHON_9_3") but I still get the message:

RtNET,"SX","!SHAPE!.firstpoint.X", "PYTHON_9_3")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3354, in CalculateField
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, you code is actually right. I've edited my answer. Are you working with a feature class that is part of a network, or is it a network layer? I made the test on a feature class within a geometric network and it failed, while it ran fine on a fc outside any relationship.

Comment: It is routed, is this the problem, should I just run the same code on the un-routed layer? Although Add Geometry did work

Comment: Yes this is apparently the problem, it's up to you remove it from the network, if the Add Geom Attributes works it's not necessary is it?

Comment: Thanks, this is only my second day using python so I'm not too good yet!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with learning Python :)